# Access - preview what an update query will change

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I am using Access to update values within a sharepoint list.
I have the sharepoint list linked as a table, and an excel file with the changes also linked in. These are linked by Purchase Order Number.

I can do an update query and it will update the appropriate values into the sharepoint  list. However I would like to "Preview" my changes before I commit them.

What I would like to do is:
Show the purchase order number (key that is common to both lists)
Show the value currently in the sharepoint list
Show what it will be updated to
Then finally tell it to go ahead and make the change

I know this is a basic question but searching doesn't seem to come up with anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a select query with the SAME criteria and send the results to a continues form with a “update” or “cancel” button. If the user hits ok, then you run your update/insert query as opposed to the select query that is displaying the data in your current form (or even report).